# Google Maps avoid (or allow) tolls only for selected country, on multi-country routing

Tags: driving, countries, tolls, google-maps

I often travel to Italy from Switzerland and vice versa, in Switzerland to use the highway you have to buy a sticker (or register your license plate online since this August) and pay a set fee for the year while Italy uses toll booths.

If I choose "avoid tolls" on Google Maps ALL the Swiss highways are excluded while in Italy Maps will tell you to use them for section where toll booths are not present. If I allow tolls the highway system of both countries is allowed.

Let's say I already have a Swiss sticker but don't want to pay the tolls in Italy (or I don't care about the Italian toll booths but I don't want to buy the yearly Swiss sticker for just one trip). Right now the only way I have found is to allow (or disallow) tolls, stop when crossing the border, disallow (or allow) tolls again and wait for the route to be recomputed.

Is there a way to tell Google Maps E.G. "Allow tolls but only for this country"?

Comment: I have the same problem - happy to pay the $2 toll in Mexico but prefer to not pay the $15 toll in California. I doubt google maps has this functionality though.

Comment: Would there be an alternative route planner that has the functionality? Cycling with a route planner I often switch between planners so I am used to having to choose a planner, but I do not know what planners for cars do

Comment: I think this would be possible with OsmAnd by adding a custom routing.xml. At least it would be simple to add [separate selector](https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-resources/blob/master/routing/routing.xml#L1003-L1005) for toll booths vs. toll routes. I'm not sure if the format allows for selection by country/region.

Comment: Waze has a slightly different solution to this. It will not guide you to use a toll pass road unless you specify that you have bought the toll pass in question. When you have, it will guide you over those roads even if you've otherwise disallowed toll roads.

Comment: You noted in a couple of comments that you're on a motorcycle. You should include that info in the question since it makes it significantly more cumbersome to change settings/apps than it would if you were in a car.

Comment: @FreeMan that was just a comment en passant, the question is not specific about one vehicle or another

Comment: Make two Google map directions, one through Switzerland and the other through Italy. If you drive it frequently, how is you haven't memorized your route yet?

Comment: @user27701 I said that I often travel between the two countries, not that I always start/arrive in the same location or cross the border from the same entry. Besides, even for routes I have memorized sometimes Google Maps suggested a different faster one I never did due to accidents, roadworks, traffic and so on

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately no.

What kind of works is to switch the 'avoid toll road' settings on and off when you cross the border. At least with Android Auto, that can be done relatively easy while driving. When doing so, you are however not guaranteed that Google Maps chooses the most optimal border crossing.

I had an even more complicated situation just a few weeks ago going through Austria to Italy. In Austria, I wanted to avoid highway tolls, but still accept that I pay for the Felbertauern tunnel and then pay highway tolls in Italy. The only solution I found for Google Maps was to manually add several intermediate stops.

What I accidentally found out when fiddling with the route and settings was also that the 'avoid toll road' setting is not always taken into account. If you for example try to route from Mittersill to Matrei in Osttirol, Google Maps will send you through the Felbertauern tunnel even if you don't want to pay tolls. The route result contains an advice that you have to pay toll for the route, so it is not that Google doesn't know that the tunnel is not free.

Comment: That's a bummer, yeah it's not so bad with Android Auto but it's really annoying when I'm on my motorbike and I have to stop, drop the kickstand, remove gloves, take out the cellphone, unlock it, disable/enable tolls, put phone back, put on gloves, get the kickstand up and drive away. All with cars zipping by...

Comment: Touch compatible gloves?

Comment: @JohnDoe even inside Schengen there can be occasional border checks, so the infrastructure is still there, and the shops, gas stations near border crossings too. So it's not like you really have to stop in the middle of a highway. You actually must not do that, it's always in the traffic regulations regardless of the country, emergency lane is for emergencies. Adjusting your phone is not an emergency. EDIT: and in the particular case of Switzerland, there is a customs border all around, so the checkpoints are even manned all the time.

Answer (score 10):

Since none of the navigation programs that I am aware of allow that,  one could use 2 navigation programs, e.g. Waze and Google Maps, configure one to avoid tolls and switch programs with a voice command when passing the border.

Comment: yeah I've experimented a bit with using multiple navigation programs but, for me, it's really cumbersome to switch between them so I was wondering if there was a solution "all in one"

Comment: @JohnDoe You could use the [”Allow tolls / Avoid tolls” voice commands](https://www.wikihow.com/Enable-Voice-Commands-in-Waze) in Waze to stay in the same app.

Comment: didn't know Waze had that option, it's still not ideal but useful nonetheless

Comment: Waze doesn't consider toll pass roads to be toll roads. It refuses to use them at all unless you have bought the required toll pass (which, at least to me, does make more intuitive sense). If you have bought the pass (and you indicate so in the settings), it will not consider those roads toll roads but "regular" roads. So the problem shouldn't happen at all if you use Waze.

Comment: @FrederikVds how does it handle road with toll booths for which you can't buy a pass but need to pay on the spot? Do you have to "green light" every single booth? I never used Waze because Google Maps was good enough but might consider it

Comment: @JohnDoe It handles those as toll roads. It's only the "toll pass" roads that are handled differently.

Comment: FYI mapy.cz ([Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.seznam.mapy), [Apple Store](https://apps.apple.com/cz/app/mapy-cz-navigation-maps/id411411020)) has this feature. Its navigation for hiking is brilliant, with the driving nav improving considerably all the time.

Answer (score 9):

If you are not wedded to Google products, then the [mapy.cz](https://www.mapy.cz) web and mobile app has this feature. Mapy.cz uses OpenStreetMap data so the maps are quite good, although may be missing some businesses etc. that Google would have.

For example, here is a route from Milan to Zurich avoiding only the Italian tolls.
https://en.mapy.cz/s/cugovejepo

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, not possible on maps.

One trick would be to check the route with tolls and take note and take note of where you enter the swiss paid road and where you cross the border.

After that, create a new route without tolls with a stop near the entrance to the swiss highway, ignore the navigator and enter the highway. After you get in Italy you can go back to follow the recalculated route, that should now lead you to get out of the paid road as soon as possible and continue onto unpaid road only.

Disclaimer: never actually tried doing it while driving but from some simualted routes, putting the starting point already on a paid road, it should work.